# How to structure httr GET request to return site data?

Tags: r, http, post, get, httr

I am Attempting to retrieve data using GET() in the httr package for R and I am receiving the error:

> Sorry Requested Method not Supported!

Code:

```
 library(httr)


 r <- GET("http://rplus.interactivedata.com/cgi/nph-rplus/Request=GET%2CIDC%2CDES1&Done=flag", 
     authenticate("xxx", "xxx")
     )
```

r

Output:

```
 Response [http://rplus.interactivedata.com/cgi/nph-       rplus/Request=GET%2CIDC%2CDES1&Done=flag]
 Date: 2016-06-06 16:19
 Status: 200
 Content-Type: text/plain
 Size: 38 B
 No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
 Sorry Requested Method not Supported!
```

I have tried many different inputs to no avail. Included is a photo of the supplied request and response info. Any help is appreciated.

[image: Request and Response]

Comment: Why do you do `GET()`, whereas the screenshot seems to want `POST()`?

Comment: Tried that as well. Neither worked for me.

Comment: This is the response I get when I use POST():       Response   [http://rplus.interactivedata.com/cgi/nph-rplus/Request=GET%2CIDC%2CDES1&Done=flag]
  Date: 2016-06-07 08:27
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: text/plain
<EMPTY BODY>